# why does instanceof return false?

Tags: javascript, null, instanceof

This is my Code

```
function Otaku (name, age) {

  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  this.habit = 'Games';
}

Otaku.prototype.strength = 60;
Otaku.prototype.sayYourName = function () {
  console.log('I am ' + this.name);
}


function newTest() {

  const obj = {}
  const ctu = [].shift.call(arguments)
  obj.__proto__ = ctu.prototype
  ctu.apply(obj, arguments)
  return obj
}
function objectFactory() {

  const obj = Object.create(null)
  Constructor = [].shift.call(arguments);
  obj.__proto__ = Constructor.prototype;
  Constructor.apply(obj, arguments);
  return obj;

};

let test = objectFactory(Otaku,'test1',11)
let test2 = newTest(Otaku,'test1',11 )

console.log(test.__proto__ === Otaku.prototype,  test instanceof Otaku, test.__proto__.Constructor)
console.log(test2.__proto__ === Otaku.prototype, test2 instanceof Otaku, test2.__proto__.Constructor)
```

But the result is unexpectedly

```
true false undefined
true true undefined
```

I think "test instanceof Otaku" Which should return TRUE,but the result is FALSE,So I compare the difference between 'test.**proto**' and 'Otaku.prototype' which result is TRUE.I guess the reason is null,but I don't understand,I need help

Comment: It's the `Object.create(null);` Explicitly making obj an object without a prototype to start with, messes with creating the proper chains to make instanceof work. if you use `const obj = Object.create({});`, instanceof does work.

Comment: i understand {} which is ok,but i print 'test.__proto' which equal to 'Otaku.prototype'

Comment: You set them correctly. But by using Object.create(null), test.__proto__ is a basic property instead of the prototype. But they still both refer to the same object, namely the prototype of Otaku. So the Otaku prototype is a prototype for Constructor, but it's a basic property for test. Hence they are equal to eachother, cause they both reference the Otaku prototype. But test is not an instance of Otaku, it's an object with the prototype of Otaku as a property, probably equivalent to if i would write: `var test = { "myproto": Otaku.prototype };`

Comment: You can see it. test does Not have the property strength or the method sayYourName, while test2 does. So test isn't an actual instance and the line `obj.__proto__ = Constructor.prototype;` does Not set the prototype of obj ( and hence, test ).

Comment: thanks,  your explanation is very good